# facing issue while loading csv file into big query using command line

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying load data into big query using bq load command but facing some issue while loading data.

I tried with bellow bq load option

```
--allow_quoted_newlines 
--allow_jagged_rows
```

getting bellow error

```
cloudshell:~ (cec-gcp-srm-prod)$ bq load  --source_format CSV  --allow_quoted_newlines --allow_jagged_rows cec_tabular_data.AIU_FaStudentPell gs://cec-srm-prod/sqoop_jars/tables/AIU_FaStudentPell/part-*
Waiting on bqjob_r7be43351d9d1ee46_0000016cd9590247_1 ... (9s) Current status: DONE   
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'cec-gcp-srm-prod:bqjob_r7be43351d9d1ee46_0000016cd9590247_1': Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors,
giving up. Rows: 53097; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.
Failure details:
- gs://cec-srm-prod/sqoop_jars/tables/AIU_FaStudentPell/part-m-00000:
Error while reading data, error message: Too many values in row
starting at position: 25633742.
```

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of the error message, the job is designed to fail once it hits 1 error.

If data accuracy is not an issue, increase the No. of errors allowed during ingest and drop the bad records.

The root cause may be that your separator appears in the csv data causing additional colums to be created. If you need 100% of the data try changing your separator from , to | or some unused symbol as that may resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks Marty! Issue is resolved, I tried with avro file format while importing data using sqoop.  where i map data with schema and then load data in big query.